# Android Remote Device Administration

Tags: android

I would like to build an enterprise application.  So in these case. i want remotely manage my Android Device,
Example.  I want to disable USB port  my office users device & New application installation.  Since device will be provided by us , So in order to main security.

How to achieve this.  Did Google Provides any APIS

Comment: I have referred a above documentation. i want to manage my user devices by sitting in the termainal ex :Remote admin  ie) i want to enable or disable USB port of my users device online.

Answer (score 0):

From the Dev Guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 0):

Android 2.2 provides a [Device Administration API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) that allows you to set certain policies for the device on which your app gets installed. There is also a step-by-step tutorial on the same page.

This API has been used in some of the existing apps that come bundled with the Android source code. For eg: Exchange Email.

The `Device Administration API` only supports certain[policies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#policies). If you need to restrict the use of the device, it might also be a good idea to tie in your app with the Exchange Email (or a corporate account, since you mentioned it's for office users). A typical corporate Exchange account has a much larger policy set.